# Python pandas merge объединяется неожиданным образом

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xls, xlsx

Вопрос следующий: 
Имеется файл xlsx в котором 3 столбца (пример ниже)
Пытаюсь выбрать данные с заданным шагом (например, 0.1 или 0.05) по столбцу Moving [mm] (точность 0.001, но необходимо учесть, что не все числа имеются, например отсутствует 0.009 и другие)

Для этого создаю DataFrame и заполняю все значения от min до max значения поля Moving [mm] с шагом 0.001.
Далее объединяю с исходным DataFrame  исходного файлa и заполняю пустые значения последующими.

Создаю массив с необходимым шагом и пытаюсь их соединить с помощью merge, получается странный вариант: есть поля NaN. Код и результат ниже.

```
Исходные данные:
Time [s]    Moving [mm] Stress [H]
0   0,0000  110,00
0,4 0,0010  110,00
0,5 0,0020  110,00
0,6 0,0030  120,00
0,7 0,0040  120,00
0,8 0,0050  140,00
1,1 0,0060  180,00
1,8 0,0070  260,00
2,5 0,0080  330,00
3,1 0,0100  380,00
3,2 0,0110  390,00
3,3 0,0120  400,00

Листинг:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    step = 0.05
    step_p=0.001    
    df = pd.read_excel("d:\python.xlsx")
    mymin=df["Moving [mm]"].min()
    mymax=df["Moving [mm]"].max()    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(mymin, mymax, step_p))
    df2 = pd.merge(df1, df, left_on=0, right_on="Moving [mm]", how='left', validate="one_to_one")
    df3 = df2.fillna(method='bfill')
    df4=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(mymin, mymax, step))
    df_ = pd.merge(df4, df3, left_on=0, right_on=0, how='left', validate="one_to_one")
    print(df4.head(20))
    print(df3.head(20))
    print(df_.head(20))

Результат: Первые 2 таблицы нормальные, третья вообще непонятная
       0
0   0.00
1   0.05
2   0.10
3   0.15
4   0.20
5   0.25
6   0.30
7   0.35
8   0.40
9   0.45
10  0.50
11  0.55
12  0.60
13  0.65
14  0.70
15  0.75
16  0.80
17  0.85
18  0.90
19  0.95
        0  Time [s]  Moving [mm]  Stress [H]
0   0.000       0.0        0.000       110.0
1   0.001       0.4        0.001       110.0
2   0.002       0.5        0.002       110.0
3   0.003       0.6        0.003       120.0
4   0.004       0.7        0.004       120.0
5   0.005       0.8        0.005       140.0
6   0.006       1.1        0.006       180.0
7   0.007       1.8        0.007       260.0
8   0.008       2.5        0.008       330.0
9   0.009       3.1        0.010       380.0
10  0.010       3.1        0.010       380.0
11  0.011       3.2        0.011       390.0
12  0.012       3.3        0.012       400.0
13  0.013       3.4        0.014       420.0
14  0.014       3.4        0.014       420.0
15  0.015       3.5        0.015       430.0
16  0.016       3.6        0.016       440.0
17  0.017       3.8        0.019       460.0
18  0.018       3.8        0.019       460.0
19  0.019       3.8        0.019       460.0
       0  Time [s]  Moving [mm]  Stress [H]
0   0.00       0.0        0.000       110.0
1   0.05       5.8        0.050       750.0
2   0.10       9.0        0.100      1170.0
3   0.15       **NaN          NaN         NaN**
4   0.20      15.4        0.201      1700.0
5   0.25      18.6        0.250      1920.0
6   0.30       **NaN          NaN         NaN**
7   0.35      25.2        0.352      2300.0
8   0.40      28.3        0.400      2470.0
9   0.45      31.6        0.450      2650.0
10  0.50      34.8        0.500      2840.0
11  0.55      38.1        0.551      3030.0
12  0.60       **NaN          NaN         NaN**
13  0.65      44.6        0.651      3420.0
14  0.70      48.2        0.704      3650.0
15  0.75      51.2        0.750      3850.0
16  0.80      54.6        0.800      4060.0
17  0.85       **NaN          NaN         NaN**
18  0.90      61.0        0.900      4500.0
19  0.95      64.9        0.960      4780.0
```

Answer (score 0):

А вы не это хотите получить?

```
df.set_index('Moving') \
  .reindex(np.arange(df['Moving'].min(), df['Moving'].max()+0.001, 0.001), method='bfill') \
  .reset_index()

    Moving  Time  Stress
0    0.000   0.0   110.0
1    0.001   0.4   110.0
2    0.002   0.5   110.0
3    0.003   0.6   120.0
4    0.004   0.7   120.0
5    0.005   0.8   140.0
6    0.006   1.1   180.0
7    0.007   1.8   260.0
8    0.008   2.5   330.0
9    0.009   3.1   380.0
10   0.010   3.1   380.0
11   0.011   3.2   390.0
12   0.012   3.3   400.0
```